# Conceptual: Create a counter in an external function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written some javascript to successfully download hundreds of files from an external site, using wget at the core.
After downloading all of the files, I would like to do some stuff with them. The issue is, the files aren't of equal size. So, the last wget formed isn't necessarily the last file downloaded, meaning I can't really tell when the last file has completed.

I do, however, know how many files there are in total, and the number associated with each wget.

I have 3 js files, [parseproducts.js] ==> [createurl.js] ==> [downloadurl.js]

Using this information, how can I tell when all of the files have been downloaded? 
 
I tried creating a "ticker" function in another file but the function resets itself on each instance, so it doesn't work at all!

**Edit: Code added** Didn't do this initially because I didn't think people would want to trawl through it! I'm new to programming/javascript/node. Please let me know if there's something that I could do better (I'm sure most of it could be more efficient!)

parseproducts.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var iset = require('./ticker.js');
var createurl = require('./createurl.js');
var array = [];

filename = 'productlist.txt';
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  content = data;
  parseFile();

});

function parseFile() {
    var stringarray = String(content).split(";");
    for (var index = 0; index < stringarray.length; ++index) {

    createurl(stringarray[index],index,stringarray.length);
    console.log(index+'/'+stringarray.length+' sent.');
    if (index === 0) {
         iset(true,stringarray.length);
    } else {
        iset (false,stringarray.length);
    }

    };
};
```

createurl.js

```
    function create(partnumber,iteration,total) {

        var JSdownloadURL = require('./downloadurl.js');

        JSdownloadURL(createurl(partnumber),partnumber,iteration,total);

        function createurl(partnumber) {
            var URL = ('"https://data.icecat.biz/xml_s3/xml_server3.cgi?prod_id='+partnumber+';vendor=hp;lang=en;output=productxml"');
            return URL;
        };
    };

module.exports = create;
```

downloadurl.js

```
function downloadurl(URL,partnumber,iteration,total) {
    // Dependencies
    var fs = require('fs');
    var url = require('url');
    var http = require('http');
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var checkfiles = require('./checkfiles.js');

    // App variables
    var file_url = URL;
    var DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';

    // We will be downloading the files to a directory, so make sure it's there
    var mkdir = 'mkdir -p ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR;
    var child = exec(mkdir, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else download_file_wget(file_url);
    });

    // Function to download file using wget
    var download_file_wget = function(file_url) {


        // compose the wget command
        var wget = 'wget  --http-user="MyAccount" --http-password="MyPassword" -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;
        // excute wget using child_process' exec function

        var child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(iteration+'/'+total+' downloaded.     '+partnumber + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);



        });
    };
};

module.exports = downloadurl;
```

*Failed attempt* ticker.js

```
function iset(bol,total) {
    if (bol === true) {
        var i = 0;
    } else {
        var i = 1;
    };
    counter(i, total);
}



function counter(i,total) {
    var n = n + i;
    if (n === (total - 1)) {
        var checkfiles = require('./checkfiles.js');
        checkfiles(total);
    } else {
    console.log('nothing done');
    };
}

module.exports = iset;
```

**Update** In response to answer

This is what my code looks like now. However, I get the error

`child_process.js:945
        throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');
              ^
    Error: spawn EMFILE`

```
// Dependencies
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var checkfiles = require('./checkfiles.js');




function downloadurl(URL,partnumber,iteration,total,clb) {
    // App variables
    var file_url = URL;
    var DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';

    // We will be downloading the files to a directory, so make sure it's there
    var mkdir = 'mkdir -p ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR;
    var child = exec(mkdir, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else download_file_wget(file_url);
    });


    var child = exec(mkdir, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            clb(err);
        } else {
            var wget = 'wget  --http-user="amadman114" --http-password="Chip10" -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;

            // excute wget using child_process' exec function
            var child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    clb(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(iteration+'/'+total+' downloaded.     '+partnumber + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
                    clb(null);  // <-- you can pass more args here if you want, like result
                    // as a general convention callbacks take a form of
                    // callback(err, res1, res2, ...)
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

function clb() {
    var LIMIT = 100,
        errs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
        downloadurl(URL,partnumber,iternation,total, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            errs.push(err);
        }
        LIMIT--;
        if (!LIMIT) {
            finalize(errs);
        }
        });
    }
}

function finalize(errs) {
    // you can now check for err
    //or do whatever stuff to finalize the code
}
module.exports = downloadurl;
```

Comment: If you declare the variable outside the function, it shouldn't reset each time.

Comment: You need to show some code, we can't tell what you're doing wrong and advise how to fix it without seeing it.

Comment: How do you download these files? Is this an asynchronous function? Are you talking about server-side JavaScript like Node.js? Is multiprocessing involved? You have to give us more details. Code would be perfect.

Comment: Will come back with some code in a few mins :)

Comment: There is two way: either wait for all download to complete before working with them, or make an array wich link a download to it s statu and maintain it.

Comment: @DrakaSAN That's what I'm trying to work out how to do

Comment: @Dan `parseproducts.js` and `createurl.js` have the same code.

Comment: @freakish Whoops, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have this function `downloadurl`. What you need to do is to pass one more argument to it: the callback. And please, move requirements outside the function and don't define a function in a function unless necessary:

```
var fs = require('fs');
// other dependencies and constants

function downloadurl(URL,partnumber,iteration,total, clb) {  // <-- new arg
    // some code
    var child = exec(mkdir, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            clb(err);
        } else {
            var wget = 'wget  --http-user="MyAccount" --http-password="MyPassword" -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;

            // excute wget using child_process' exec function
            var child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    clb(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(iteration+'/'+total+' downloaded.     '+partnumber + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
                    clb(null);  // <-- you can pass more args here if you want, like result
                    // as a general convention callbacks take a form of
                    // callback(err, res1, res2, ...)
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

This look nicer, doesn't it? Now when you call that function multiple times you do:

```
var LIMIT = 100,
    errs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
    downloadurl(..., function(err) {
        if (err) {
            errs.push(err);
        }
        LIMIT--;
        if (!LIMIT) {
            finalize(errs);
        }
    });
}

function finalize(errs) {
    // you can now check for err
    //or do whatever stuff to finalize the code
}
```

That's a general idea. You have to tweak it to your needs (in particular you have to modify the intermediate function to accept a callback as well). Of course there are libraries which will take care of most this for you like [kriskowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) (`Q.all`) or [caolan's async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (`async.parallel`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestions. I'm just a bit confused as to how to use your 'limit' code. I have updated my question

Comment: @Dan It means that you've opened too many file descriptors. You are issuing too many jobs parallely. Either increase `ulimit` (google it) or implement some kind of queue which will not allow you to issue more then say 20 parallel requests.

Comment: Ah, ok. The way I implemented the code itself is right though?

Comment: @Dan Sort of. The second code piece of code I've written should be used as an example and instead the stuff you do in `parseFile` function. You call `createurl` function there which is again unnecessary (the function is really short and simple). You can rewrite it to only use `downloadurl` function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the problem correctly as I don't see the code. I have worked on creating a download engine. I used to make background AJAX calls to download files. After every successful download or 'onComplete' event I used to increment one variable to keep track of downloaded files. Provdided user won't refresh the page till all the download is complete. Else the download counter can be saved in LocalStorage also.

Comment: Judging from the fact that he's using wget I assume that he's talking about server-side JavaScript. Other then that the idea with `onComplete` handler is absolutely correct.